# Datagridcombo box not populating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Good day,

I have a program that pulls data from a database. I am using WPF and MVVM. I am EXTREMELY new to this (limited vba experience however). The program displays correctly the right data but I am trying to change a field "Priority" so when you click on it there is a combobox which I can select a new value from a list which will then in turn update the database.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProgramID}" Header="Program ID" Width="100" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cedant}" Header="Cedant" Width="300" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UWCode}" Header="Underwriter" Width="145"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateSubmitted}" Header="Date Submitted" Width="145"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RequiredDate}" Header="Required Date" Width="145"/>
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Priority}" ItemsSource="{Binding Priority}" SelectedValuePath="Priority" Header="Priority" DisplayMemberPath="Priority" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" Width="145"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AssignedTo}" Header="Assigned To" Width="125"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EffectiveDate}" Header="ResponseDate" Width="145"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Modeler}" Header="Modeller" Width="125"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
```

you can see its about the middle entry which I am trying to mess with. If i put it as a datagridtextcolumn it works just fine.

```
namespace DataModel.Model
{

    public class ModelRequest
    {
         [Key, Column(Order = 1), StringLength(255)]
         public int ProgramID { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string Cedant { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string UWCode { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string Priority { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string Status { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string AssignedTo { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string Modeler { get; set; }

         [StringLength(255)]
         public string Prod_Office { get; set; }

    }
}
```

above is my model

not sure what else you need to see.

My question is, a) how do i get this combobox to first display the data like it did and then how do I add value options

b) how do I then link those value options to update a database? 
the ssql to run is

```
sSQL = "update tbl_ModelRequest " & _
     "Set priorityID=" & Priority & " " & _
    "where programid=" & ProgramID
```

Comment: fix your tags please..

Answer (score 0):

Found mistake, there was a spelling error elsewhere!